# php require command error

Tags: php, require

I have a home.php file which references fileA using php require command which is in the same folder i.e. localhost. the code is:

```
<?php // /localhost/home.php
require ('/fileA.php');
?>
```

fileA references another file in its code fileB.
so far its workin properly
when i access `fileC.php`
i reference fileA using

```
<?php // /localhost/A/B/fileC.php
require ('../../fileA.php');
?>
```

the code is able to acquire fileA but only works properly when fileB is in the same folder as fileC else produces a 404 error.I am not able to understand why is this happening since fileB is called by fileA.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using relative file paths, keep in mind that they are relative to your current working directory, not to file that performs inclusion. current working directory is set automatically on the first request (`A/B` in your case).

Some simple solutions: always use `dirname(__FILE__)` before including file, this way it be relative to the file the is in:

```
<?php 
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/FileA.php"); 
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../FileB.php");
```

Comment: By `dirname(__FILE__)`, you mean `__DIR__`? :)

Comment: Yes, but `__DIR__` is only avaliable since php 5.3, `dirname` also works for older php installations.

Comment: but i dont have to call fileB from fileC , fileB is called from fileA

Comment: So by your argument the folder that has fileA must then be set as current working directory since fileA is called perfectly.

Comment: `FileA` is included, because it is referenced from current working directory. If in your `FileA` you have `require('FileB')`, than php will search for `FileB` in `A/B` (where `FileC` resides) sice it is current working directory. Of course you can also change current working directory, but this often leads to more confusion with paths.